# How to get all fields along with value of Composite object?

Tags: java, reflection

I am facing issue to get value of all fields of a class by reflaction.

I have one class which can have any number of fields, any number of classes and those classes in turn can have any number of fields, something like as below

```
public class A{
    String string;
    int number;
    HashMap<String,String> map;
    B bclass;
}
```

Above B is again class member of class A.

1. I want to get fields of type **String** and their's values and if field is class
2. If field is **Class** again, then get fields and values , for example, **map** property is of type **HashMap** class type then I need both key and value properties which are of **String** type.

Please see my code snippet to solve above problem

```
private void extractStringFields(Object object) throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Field field : object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {

        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("filesd : "+field.getName());
        Object value = field.get(object);

        if (field.getType().equals(String.class)) {
            System.out.println(field.getName() + "=" + value);
        }
        extractStringFields(field);
    }
}
```

But unfortunately, its not working, help me please.

Comment: HashMap doesn't have fields/values of type String (what you are looking at are its generic parameters). I *do* believe you are asking how to get all fields of an object and its contained variables, recursively. Question is, what are you supposed to return at the end?

Comment: The first issue is that, due to type erasure, generic classes have fields of type `Object`. The second issue is that you probably don't want any fields in a `HashMap` as they are private for a reason. And finally you probably want to call the recursive method in the `else` to your `if` and with the `field's` value rather than the `field` its self. Also, how will you avoid infinite loops?

Comment: for me HashMap will always have String type values, and I need both key and value as a String

Answer (score 0):

When you are passing,

```
extractStringFields(field);
```

it is sending a Field object. So when 2nd call onwards object.getClass will give you Field.class. For this you will never get proper value.

Better you keep another overloaded class, you pass Field there. In that method you can write this,

```
for (Field field : field.getType().getDeclaredFields())
```

Hope this will give you a head start.

or you can use this:

```
if(value != null){
                extractStringFields(value);
            }
```

Comment: I have tested this. it is working. Just check if any object holds same type of object or not. in that case it will go for a infinite loop. you need to handle thus. I used the second solution.